# Comparing jsonresult with string

Tags: java, android, json

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result.equals("complete")) {

            try{

                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logging in...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(context,Show.class);
                    startActivity(i);}

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Invalid UserID/Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(context, "NO Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();

           }
}
```

I am returning a "true" if login is successful and a "false" if the login is not successful as a JSONstring but the control is not going in the if block. It is directly going to else block regardless of the jsonstring value.

Comment: and whats the json you are getting...i don't think its value is true..and tell me what is "s" variable ?

Comment: where are you getting the value of the variable s from?

Comment: put both of your json response for successful and unsuccessful login.

Comment: and also put the code of how you are parsing the data

Comment: Simply use `equals()` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase()`. It will work.

Comment: where is your json string?

Comment: jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
s=jsonResult;
and in my php i am returning "true" if login succesful
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
  if($row['password'] == "$pass")
 
 $flag="true";
 else $flag="false";
} 

$conn->close();

echo (json_encode($flag));

Comment: Can you show your received json text?